# How to make a .dart file in flutter app dynamically? (Dynamic page building in Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I have a flutter app that has an option of adding a event. So what I want to do is that as soon as we add a new event, a new page should build up for the newly added event (like creating a .dart file or using some flutter component to do so). It should render the newly added event data from firebase in a dynamically created flutter page. How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your asking but i think that you want to make an .dart file with your Page as a class (as a template), which you will create instances of when you get data from firebase.

As every OOP language you can pass arguments to classes.
Here you have tutorial: https://www.flutterbeads.com/pass-data-to-stateful-widget-in-flutter/

hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).